# React Tab.Navigator does not maintain scroll position when tab is changed with detachInactiveScreens={false} . How to maintain the position?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make a React-Native app that has multiple tabs and two of them contains FlatList. Now I want tab switching to be super fast and for that I have used detachInactiveScreens={false} prop in the Tab.Navigator which works fine and makes the app fast (as expected). But when the tab is changed and previous tab is opened, it opens instantly ,But the scroll position goes to top and screen looks like it opened for the first time. I want the screen to remain at the exact same position where it was when the Tab was changed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to help without some code.  But that is quite simple in theory - listen for a scroll event, record scroll position on each event , when you navigate to that screen, check if there is a value recorded and apply that to the scroll.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @AleksandarZoric for the info ,But the solution was achieved by making detachInactiveScreens={true} and caching the FlatList items(react-native-video) in the local storage. Problem has been solved. Thanks.